# Jqgrid Traversing through Alldata

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to JQgrid and trying to execute a requirement for my project.

I need to traverse through all the data fetched from

**var allJQGridData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','data');**

I want to traverse through allJQGridData to retrieve the data from the (object object) and get the individual rows from the above allJQGridData variable.

Can you please help me i am struck here. I have the rowID's for which i want to retrieve the data.

Thanks,
Balaji Kharade

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's important to understand that `data` parameter will be filled only if one use local data (`datatype: "local"`) or if one loads the remote data in `loadonce: true` scenario. jqGrid saves the input data in the array `data` and in the map `_index`. The `_index` hold the map between the rowids and index in the `data` array. The method `getLocalRow` simplifies access the row data from `data` by rowid.

Thus you can get the object with the row data in the way

```js
var rowData = grid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid);
```

You can use the following code to enumerate all rowids and the data in the grid:

```js
var localGridData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
    idsToDataIndex = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index'),
    id, rowData;

for (id in idsToDataIndex) {
    if (idsToDataIndex.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        rowData = idsToDataIndex[id];
        // the same as rowData = grid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', id);
        console.log(rowData);
    }
}
```